# Kendo Grid updated on change on option tag element

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I need to update my Kendo Grid on change event on option element.
I have to element and depending on one or two of them my backend implementation will return different records. But I do not know how to call something like

```
('myKendoGrid').update('myUrl?zoneId=4')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to get the data and refresh the grid based on returned results

```
$('#selectZone').change(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'myUrl',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { zoneId: id},
            success: function (data) {
                var grid = $('#grid').getKendoGrid();
                grid.dataSource.data(data);
                grid.refresh();
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Because I transfer DataSourceResult I did grid.dataSource.data(data.Data) but now, when I try to update, I receive a message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. That is my schema and I am not sure what I did wrong:
schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    errors: "Errors",
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: I dont understand. Can you add a new question with complete details and share the link?

Comment: The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829082/cannot-update-value-in-kendo-grid-cannot-read-data-property-of-undegined