# Cannot update value in Kendo-grid - cannot read 'data' property of undegined

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I am updating Kendo-grid when the selected value in option HTML element is changed. But when I try to update the value in the grid inline in the browser's console is printed "kendo.web.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

What Did I wrong?

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
  
  // on changing zone option selector
    $('#SelectProviderZoneForPrices').change(function (e) {
      var zoneId = $(this).val();
      var productId = $('#SelectProviderForPrices').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("LoadZoneWeights", "ShippingZonableByWeight"))",
        success: loadPrices, // loads the shipping providers which delivers by zones
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { ProviderId: productId, ZoneId: zoneId }});
    });

    // loads prices
    function loadPrices(data) {
      var grid = $('#shippingProviderWeightPrice-grid').getKendoGrid();
      grid.dataSource.data(data.Data); // my backend returns DataSourceResult
      grid.refresh();
    }
  
    // load Kendo-grid
    $("#shippingProviderWeightPrice-grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
          read: {
            url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller"))",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
          },
          update: {
            url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller"))",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
          }
        },
        schema: {
          total: "Total",
          errors: "Errors",
          model: {
            fields: {
              ProviderWeightsId: {
                editable: false,
                visible: false,
                type: "number"
              },
              ZoneId: {
                editable: false,
                visible: false,
                type: "number"
              },
              ZoneName: {
                editable: false,
                visible: false,
                type: "string"
              },
              WeightFrom: {
                editable: false,
                visible: true,
                type: "number"
              },
              WeightTo: {
                editable: false,
                visible: true,
                type: "number"
              },
              Price: {
                editable: true,
                visible: true,
                type: "number"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        requestEnd: function(e) {
          if (e.type == "update") {
            this.read();
          }
        },
        error: function(e) {
          display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
          this.cancelChanges();
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
      },
      pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        numeric: false,
        previousNext: false,
        info: false
      },
      editable: {
        confirmation: true,
        mode: "inline"
      },
      scrollable: false,
      columns: [{
        field: "WeightFrom",
        title: "Weight From",
        format: "{0:n3}",
        width: 100
      }, {
        field: "WeightTo",
        title: "Weight To",
        format: "{0:n3}",
        width: 100
      }, {
        field: "Price",
        title: "Price",
        format: "{0:n3}",
        width: 100
      }, {
        command: [{
          name: "edit",
          text: "Edit"
        }]
      }]
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend><strong>Manage Weights</strong>
  </legend>
  <table class="adminContent">
    <tr>
      <td class="adminTitle">Select Provider</td>
      <td class="adminData">
        <select id="SelectProviderForPrices" name="ProviderId">
          <option value="0">- Select Provider -</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="adminTitle">Select Zone</td>
      <td class="adminData">
        <select id="SelectProviderZoneForPrices" name="ProviderId">
          <option value="0">- Select Zone -</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<br/>
<div id="shippingProviderWeightPrice-grid">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I was removed the id property in my datasource-model of the grid and that caused my problems. I don't know why it is so big deal - especially when I could have objects without ID. But now it is fine.

```js
id: "ProviderWeightsId",
fields: {
  ProviderWeightsId: { editable: false, visible: false, type: "number" },
  ZoneId: { editable: false, visible: false, type: "number" },
  ZoneName: { editable: false, visible: false, type: "string" },
  WeightFrom: { editable: false, visible: true, type: "number" },
  WeightTo: { editable: false, visible: true, type: "number" },   
  Price: { editable: true, visible: true, type: "number" }
}
```

Comment: You should add this to your original post.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `data` to the `loadPrices` function.

```
$('#SelectProviderZoneForPrices').change(function (e) {
      var zoneId = $(this).val();
      var productId = $('#SelectProviderForPrices').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("LoadZoneWeights", "ShippingZonableByWeight"))",
        success: function (data) {  
            loadPrices(data); //pass data to loadPrices function
        }
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { ProviderId: productId, ZoneId: zoneId }});
    });
```

**Update:**

Try this :

```
public ActionResult LoadZoneWeights(int ProviderId, int ZoneId)
{

  var zoneWeights = _shippingService.GetZonesWithWeights(ProviderId, ZoneId);


  return Json(zoneWeights , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and

```
 schema: {
        data: function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: kendo.web.min.js:13 **Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a functionlt.extend.data** @ kendo.web.min.js:13 loadWeights @ ConfigureProvider?systemName=Shipping.ZonableByWeight:1379$.ajax.success @ ConfigureProvider?systemName=Shipping.ZonableByWeight:1358c @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21p.fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21k @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23r @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23

Comment: Can you put your controller method `LoadZoneWeights`?

Comment: @BorisTodorov Check my update, see if helps. Its difficult to debug without knowing what data is being received. You should also check in fiddler to see data being received. Also, edit your question to add details instead of adding answer

Comment: I found the problem. I was removed the id property in my datasource-model of the grid and that caused my problems. I don't know why it is so big deal - especially when I could have objects without ID. But now it is fine.

Comment: Nice! You should add you working code in your answer. It might help someone else stumbling upon this in future